# Finding the Rank of Upper Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

If $A$ is the upper triangular matrix of order $n$, given below, is it possible to work out, (or at least bound) its rank?

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 100 & \star & \dots & \star & \star \\
    0 & 0 & \star & \dots & \star & \star \\
    0 & 0 &  203 & \dots & \star & \star \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \star & \star \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \star & \star \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \star
    \end{bmatrix}
$

Where each $\star$ represents any number (not necessarily the same) from $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Is it possible to have $\star = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $\star$ is allowed to be zero.

We attain the minimal possible rank by setting each $\star = 0$. Any matrix in this pattern will necessarily have rank at least $2$ because we always have the rank $2$ submatrix
$$
\pmatrix{100&\star \\0 & 203}
$$
We attain the maximal possible rank by setting each $\star = 1$.  Since the matrix is in row-echelon form, the rank is simply the number of leading non-zero entries, which is $n-1$.  We cannot attain rank $n$ because the first column is always $0$.

It is possible to attain any rank in between by setting columns equal to $0$.

Comment: Is it true that the rank of an Upper Triangular Matrix is greater than or equal to the number of non-zero diagonal entries?

Comment: @s yes this is true